# Compiled LINQ for dynamic query

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Is it possible to use compiled LINQ in Dynamic LINQ query?

There is this function.

```
protected IQueryable<DbT> GetPage(TTMSDataContext db, IQueryable<DbT> query, int maximumRows, int startRowIndex)
{
    return query.Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);
}
```

Its been used by multiple linq query execution. Is it possible to apply complied LINQ in this function?.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't compile a dynamic query like that.  You may be able to compile the queries that call that function, maybe.

Are you trying to compile it so that it executes faster, or is there another reason?

Comment: Yes.. i am trying to compile it so that it executes faster. @Robert Mckee .. Could you suggest any idea to do that.

Comment: I would suggest looking at using a profiler and seeing what SQL gets generated, then going from there.  This function likely isn't the (major) cause of any performance issues.  You might find you are missing an index that you need.